# Get ID from one tabe and find name for that ID

Tags: php, mysql

In my data base I have 3 tables.

user  (table name) 
so many row are there  one of the row name user and if

```
--------------------
| id | user        |
--------------------
| 7  | user        |
| 8  | user_name_2 |
| 11 | user_name_5 |
--------------------
```

and another table call data

```
----------------------------
| id | user-id | number    |
----------------------------
| 1  | 7       | 789654125 |
| 2  | 8       | 465654545 |
| 3  | 11      | 884554511 |
----------------------------
```

In table td user_id is table user id

now I want to show name and number in php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","QAZWS12","user");
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM user"  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
}
```

did the same and get `$number = $row["number"]`

Now I want is  in data table user id auto get table user number   how can i do that?

Final output

user 789654125
user_name_2  465654545  like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use join here. For more details on different types JOINS refer either official MySQL doc or search online

replace this query

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id,u.user AS user_name,d.number AS user_number 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN  description d ON  u.id = d.user-id";
```

The above query will fetch user id and username and user number

replace this too

```
$id = $row["id"].' '.$row['user_name'].' '.$row['user_number'].'<br/>';
```

This outputs as 
7 user 789654125

Answer (score 1):

Try below SQL query with LEFT JOIN to get the username with their mobile number in the result set:

```
$sql =  "SELECT u.user, d.number 
         FROM user as u 
         LEFT JOIN data as d ON d.user-id = u.id
        "
```

Answer (score 1):

user SQL Left join

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN call_data ON user.id = call_data.user-id";
```

while accessing data

```
$number = $row['number'];
```

learn about [SQL JOINS TUTORIAL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)